# Error 500 when try to create bill invoices by batch in Xero

Tags: python, xero-api

I always get error 500 when I try to create bill invoices by batch in xero. When I send the same invoices one by one - all ok.
The whole text of that exception:

```
     xero.exceptions.XeroInternalError: {"Title":"An error occurred","Detail":"An error occurred in Xero. Check the API Status page http://status.developer.xero.com for current service status.","Status":500,"Instance":"5613754b-f382-431c-9bc9-8e3e2cdb1bd7"}
```

I use python with pyxero library. This problem appear only with purchase invoices. Where can the problem be?

Comment: Error 500 usually means that there's something wrong with the data you submitted, either something missing, or something badly formatted. If individual invoices work but batch invoices do not, that suggests something wrong with how you are formatting the group, but as far as I know (in ACCREC, at least) every invoice you submit is done so as part of a batch of invoices, but just as a batch of one. So in theory when you send a single invoice, you're also sending a batch. Maybe some more detail - or your code - might help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I noticed that when I send batches of 10 all ok. If I send more that problem appears. But even if i send 10 bills it sends veeeeeery slowly. I have about 10 000 bills.
The example of batch looks like this https://hastebin.com/uguxedosar.yaml. I put here only 2 batches.
P.S. Contact is list because I have seen this resolving with similar problem, but it doesn't help.

Comment: If you submit the data using the Previewer on the developer site, does it give any more information on what might be wrong?

Comment: Tried it few minutes ago. Got the same error... Have you tried to send batches of purchase invoices?

Comment: No, sorry, I haven't done either purchase invoices, or batches.